# Rubymine 6.3 freezes sporadically since I upgraded to Yosemite

Tags: rubymine, osx-yosemite

[image]

In the screenshot you can see that this time when rubymine froze, it took up ove 130% of the CPU, which doesn't really make much sense. In some cases this number was over 200%.

Any ideas why this issue happens and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm getting the same problem and haven't found any solutions.  No word from JetBrains either.